# convert date string to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have date string in format `dd-MMM-yyyy` and want to convert this to `datetime`, when I use below code

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20-Oct-2012", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", null)
```

it causing an error

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

When I modify above code

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20-Oct-2012", "dd-MMM-yyyy", null)
```

then I got date time in format (`mm/dd/yyyy`) : `10/20/2012 12:00:00 AM`

But I need it should be converted in `yyyy/mm/dd` format. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Comment: My requirement is datetime variable containing date in format "yyyy/MM/dd"

when I used below code
DateTime ConvertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20-Oct-2012", "dd-MMM-yyyy", null);

Converted date contain value "10/20/2012 12:00:00 AM".

But I need ParsExact method should convert in different format 2010/10/20 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 6):

You should try this

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20-Oct-2012", "dd-MMM-yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")
```

For further reading on formats [Check This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14743/Easy-String-to-DateTime-DateTime-to-String-and-For)

Comment: sorry, above code will convert it in to string but I need to convert this in datetime datatype with format as yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: My requirement is datetime variable containing date in format "yyyy/MM/dd"

when I used below code
DateTime ConvertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20-Oct-2012", "dd-MMM-yyyy", null);

Converted date contain value "10/20/2012 12:00:00 AM".

But I need ParsExact method should convert in different format 2010/10/20 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between two separate concerns: that of parsing your original string into an abstract `DateTime` representation, and that of converting the latter back into another string representation.

In your code, you're only tackling the former, and relying on the implicit `ToString()` method call (which uses the system's current locale) to convert it back to string. If you want to control the output format, you need to specify it explicitly:

```
// Convert from string in "dd-MMM-yyyy" format to DateTime.
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20-Oct-2012", "dd-MMM-yyyy", null);

// Convert from DateTime to string in "yyyy/MM/dd" format.
string str = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Also note that the `mm` format specifier represents minutes; months are represented by `MM`.

**Edit**: 'Converted date contain value "10/20/2012 12:00:00 AM".' Be careful what you mean by that. The constructed `DateTime` value contains an abstract representation of the parsed date and time that is *independent* of any format.

However, in order to display it, you need to convert it back into some string representation. When you view the variable in the debugger (as you're presumably doing), Visual Studio automatically calls the parameterless [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx) method on the `DateTime`, which renders the date and time under the current culture (which, in your case, assumes the US culture).

To alter this behaviour such that it renders the date and time under a custom format, you need to explicitly call the [`ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) overload (or one of the other overloads), as I've shown in the example above.

Comment: My requirement is datetime variable containing date in format "yyyy/MM/dd"

when I used below code
DateTime ConvertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20-Oct-2012", "dd-MMM-yyyy", null);

Converted date contain value "10/20/2012 12:00:00 AM".

But I need ParsExact method should convert in different format 2010/10/20 12:00:00 AM

Comment: @VinodChakote: Refer to edit above for an expanded explanation.

Comment: Hi Douglas, Thanks for your reply, my issue is when I use DateTime.ParseExact then return datetime value is in "mm/dd/yyyy" format, also when I use convert.toDatetime then value is in "mm/dd/yyyy" format. But I need such method which return value in DateTime data type with format "yyyy/mm/dd" format.

Comment: The `DateTime` value is *not* in "mm/dd/yyyy" format. Re-read my edit carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead :

```
Convert.ToDateTime("20-Oct-2012").ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: My requirement is datetime variable containing date in format "yyyy/MM/dd" when I used below code DateTime ConvertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20-Oct-2012", "dd-MMM-yyyy", null); Converted date contain value "10/20/2012 12:00:00 AM". But I need ParsExact method should convert in different format 2010/10/20 12:00:00 AM

Comment: @VinodChakote, do you need to get the date in **dd-MMM-yyyy** format?